# How to download image from firebase storage using NextJs?

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

We are using the below code for download the image in Nextjs:

```
const handleDownload = async (fileUrl: string) => { 
  try { 
    const storageRef = ref(storage, fileUrl); 
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = downloadURL;
    downloadLink.target = "_blank";
    // Set the desired file name
    downloadLink.download = "file_name.ext"; 
    downloadLink.textContent = "Download File";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occurred during the download
    console.error("Error downloading file:", error);
  }
};
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a reference to your file in storage:

```
const storage = getStorage()
const ref = ref(storage, 'path/to/image.ext')
const url = await getDownloadURL(ref)
```

Then, if you want to download the image, you can use `XMLHttpRequest`, `axios` or any other similar library to fetch download url:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = (event) => {
  const blob = xhr.response;
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

Or, if you want do display the image, you can just create a new `img` tag:

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', url);
```

You can read more about downloading files from firebase storage [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?hl=pt-br)